# Promise.all error handling — make result of one Promise accessible in another Promise's catch?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, promise

I'm writing a simple build script which compiles some files. The only problem remaining is the error handling. It works, but I want add additional content to the error messages. Here is a snippet of the code in question:

```
const promises = []

for (let file of files) {
  promises.push(Promise.all([exec(compile(file)), Promise.resolve(file)]))
}

Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(e => console.log(e))))
.then(result => {
  /* result is now an array with the following pattern:
     [[stdout, filename], [stdout, filename], ...]
   */
});
```

The `exec` function returns some `stdout` containing data which does not state which file was used. Therefore I have added a `Promise.all` containing both the exec function and a promise which immediately resolve and return the filename. I need the data returned from exec and the filename for when I need to write the files to the system. Because I still want the last `then` to run regardless of any errors, I handle the errors for each file individually (hence the `.map`). The only issue is that the `stdout` from `exec` does not reference the file it used. So the error messages get confusing. I would something like the following:

```
p.catch(e => console.log(`error happened in ${file}:`, e))
```

I'm not sure how I can access the file variable from within the `catch`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should directly add the catch when calling the function:

```
  for (let file of files) {
    promises.push(
       exec(compile(file))
         .then(result => [result, file])
         .catch(error => [error, file])
    );
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    //...
  });
```

Comment: `file` will always be the last item in the `files` array if I do it this way. Not sure why though.

Comment: @audun are you sure you used `let file` ?

Comment: Ah my bad! I did not, I used `var`. It works with `let`. I rewrote some code to make my question simpler and along to way I inattentively wrote let.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to put the `catch` in the loop where the respective `file` is still in scope:

```
Promise.all(files.map(file => 
  Promise.all([
    exec(compile(file)).catch(e => console.log(`error happened in ${file}:`, e)),
    file
  ])
)).then(result => {
  /* result is now an array with the following pattern:
     [[stdout/undefined, filename], [stdout/undefined, filename], ...]
   */
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! Also kudos for noting that the `Promise.resolve(file)` was superflous.

Comment: Why use the nested `Promise.all` at all then?

Comment: @JonasWilms It's just a cheap way of writing `.then(result => [result, file])`. I left it as the OP had used the same approach.